# Magento 2 How to check third party extension except magento extension in vendor folder

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, magento2.4.3.p1, vendor

Magento 2
From now all extensions should be installed via the composer.

How can we check the third-party extension in the Magento vendor folder?, while installing Magento 2 then Magento have also lots of different extensions in its vendor folder, so we need to find only third-party extension which is not coming from the default.

For example, we installed 5-8 third-party extensions in Magento, and that extensions are present in the vendor folder or vendor/magento folder but need to find only third-party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

config.php consist list of all extensions.

You can grep all extension list which does not include 'Magento_' using below command.
It will find and list all extensions excepting "Magento"
Give it a try :

```
grep -L "Magento_" app/etc/config.php
```